Error in citing conference paper in BibTex
Could someone help me to find why are my TeX code formatting become like this ?. I think there's no problem with the book, but there's something wrong with formatting of paper conference (inproceedings).

here's the references.bib. I use references.bib as the file for storing the bibliography
@book{knuth2001art,
    title={The Art of Computer Programming: Fundamental Algorithms},
    author={Knuth, D.E.},
    number={v. 1},
    isbn={9780201896831},
    series={The Art of Computer Programming: Fundamental Algorithms},
    year={2001},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley}
}
@INPROCEEDINGS{4026885,
    author={W. Vogels},
    booktitle={2006 IEEE International Conference on Services Computing (SCC'06)},
    title={Web Services at Amazon.comm},
    year={2006},
    %pages={xxii-xxii},
   % keywords={Distributed computing;Technological innovation;Web services},
   % doi={10.1109/SCC.2006.116},
   % month={sep}
}
@inproceedings{mypaper,
  title        = {An Analysis of Example},
  author       = {John Smith and Jane Doe},
  year         = 2022,
  month        = {June},
  booktitle    = {Proceedings of the International Conference on Example},
  publisher    = {ACM Press},
  address      = {New York, NY},
  series       = {Example Conference Proceedings},
  volume       = 1,
  number       = 2,
  pages        = {123--130},
  editor       = {David Brown and Susan Green},
  organization = {ACM}
}

and for the configuration, i use this this
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{references.bib}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Two lines of the LaTeX document + the relevant part of the bib are not enough to reproduce the problem. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.
